# Update columns which included in payload

Tags: mysql, rest, go

I have a struct mapping to mysql table as below and want to update fields which are sent in a PUT request payload

```
type Notification struct {
 Id                 int64     `json:"id"`
 Type               NotificationType
 Subject            string    `json:"confidence"`
 Body               string    `json:"body"`
 CreatedDate        time.Time `json:"created_dt"`
 CreatedBy          int64     `json:"created_by"`
 ParentNotification int64     `json:"parent_id"`
 IsExpired          bool      `json:"expired"`
}
```

Currently I am asking all the fields to be included in payload even though the data is not changed and updating all columns using query with **db.Exec(query)** statement.

Is there any way where I can ask client to include only fields which are changed in payload and update only those fields?

```
{
 "body" : "new body"
 "subject" : "new subject"
}
```

I am working with below packages in db side.

```
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ask client to include only fields which are changed in payload and update only those fields"? do you want a method to send the request or how to handle the request?

Comment: The client program can send one field as payload or all fields as payload and in htt handler I need to update fields which they send. If payload 
 is {"body" : "newbody"} -then query =  "update tbl set body="newbody" where id = id . If payload is {"subject" : "new", "body" : "new"} then query = "update tbl set subject="new", body="new" where id = 1

Comment: Simply you can decode the payload to your Notification struct and validate this struct as per your app logic, then update the database accordingly with non-null fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do what you want, that is, have the client send only data that they want to change, is to have one extra "param" type per each "db table" type. So, for example, given your `Notification` type you would have a `NotificationParams` type like so:

```
type NotificationParams struct {
    Id      int64 `json:"id"`
    // use pointers so that a field that is not present in the json
    // will result in a nil pointer value, which tells you that no
    // update is needed for that column, it also allows the client
    // to send an empty string if they want to delete the content of
    // some column, e.g. Body.
    Type    *NotificationType
    Subject *string `json:"confidence"`
    Body    *string `json:"body"`
    // and other fields that you want to allow the client change
}
```

And then in your handler or whereever you can do something along these lines:

```
params := &NotificationParams{} // unmarshal from json
notif := &Notification{} // read from db using params.Id

// change only those fields that were provided
if params.Type != nil {
    notif.Type = *params.Type
}
if params.Subject != nil {
    notif.Subject = *params.Subject
}
if params.Body != nil {
    notif.Body = *params.Body
}

// do some validation...

// if ok save notif using mysql UPDATE
```

---

#### Update

If you want to avoid having to write a large number of `if` statements you could write a couple of "setter" or "apply" functions (whichever name you like more) that do that for you, one for each type that you want to support, e.g. one for `string`, one for `time.Time`, etc.

Take this function for example:

```
// The variadic list of functions can be used to transform (think
// sanitization, normalization, etc.) the value before setting
// it to the dst pointer.
func ApplyStr(dst, src *string, fns ...func(string) string) {
    if src != nil {
        s := *src
        for _, fn := range fns {
            s = fn(s)
        }

        *dst = s
    }
}
```

And then you would use such a function like in [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/i1c4D6lwY2).

Comment: Thanks mkopriva.  This will work and I was going on same path. However I was checking if we can achieve this by less if else. I got good number of put requests where i need to achieve this functionality.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @BinishJohn also if you have access to the old record before you do the unmarshaling, you can just unmarshal the data into it. That is: 1st-step get the record from the db; 2nd-step unmarshal the json into it. The json unmarshaler will not touch fields that do not have a corresponding value in the json, leaving the old field values unchanged. And if you need to "protect" some fields from being changed, you can embed the Notification in a struct that declares those fields as well and then the unmarshaler will set those instead of the ones on the Notification itself.

Comment: @BinishJohn an example illustrating the concept in my previous comment: https://play.golang.org/p/erh0y8OmH8

Comment: Thanks :).  Solves it. I can extend it to suite my service. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The following method uses [GORM](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/) library to persist your data after receiving the payload:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    "time"
)


type NotificationType struct {
    gorm.Model

}

type Notification struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id                 int64     `json:"id"`
    Type               NotificationType
    Subject            string    `json:"confidence"`
    Body               string    `json:"body"`
    CreatedDate        time.Time `json:"created_dt"`
    CreatedBy          int64     `json:"created_by"`
    ParentNotification int64     `json:"parent_id"`
    IsExpired          bool      `json:"expired"`
}

func main() {
    //your handler code to receive and decode payload from client


    //save data to database
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&Notification{})

    // Read
    var Notification notification
    db.First(&notification, 1) // find notification with id 1 , the id from your payload

    // Update the table from notification object
    db.Save(&notification)
}
```